# SQL Server character set and N prefix

Tags: sql-server, character-encoding, sql-server-2008-express

[THIS IS **NOT** A QUESTION ABOUT **NVARCHAR** OR HOW TO STORE CHINESE CHARACTER]

SQL Server 2008 Express

Database collation is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`

```
create table sample1(val varchar(2))
insert into sample1 values(N'中文')
```

1. I know these Chinese characters would become junk characters.
2. I know I can use nvarchar to overcome all problem.

What I don't know is: why there isn't "string too long" error when I run the insert statement?

1. N prefix means that client will encode the string using UNICODE.
2. 2 Chinese characters will become 4 bytes.
3. varchar(2) can only contain 2 bytes.

Why people down vote this question? really?

Comment: Well, SQL Server sees that you're inserting into a `varchar` column and therefore it will **automagically** convert that string you've passed in into a non-unicode, `varchar` compatible string of two characters. Two characters is not too big for this column to store....

Comment: First thing is varchar can not store such characters directly, it converts them, so normally we use nvarchar. you can try this             create table sample3(val nvarchar(2))
    insert into sample3 values(N'中文')

Comment: I know it's not a question about storing chinese. Like I told you, an implied cast takes place and stores it in your varchar as "??" (at least on my codepage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More explanation to @marc_s answer.

The character `N'中文'` will be converted to `varchar` with the collation `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`. Since there is no such character in the code page, it will converted to not defined, and `0x3f3f` in the end. `0x3f` is the question mark, so there will be *two* question marks in this case and it won't exceed the column length.

Answer (score 2):

An implied cast takes place. This would work if "val" was created as nvarchar(2).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use *NVARCHAR(...), NCHAR(...)* datatypes -

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.sample1
(
    val NVARCHAR(4)
)
INSERT INTO dbo.sample1 
SELECT N'中文'
```